# Different .dvi file depending on how do I compile .tex file

Tags: compiling, kile, dvi

I'm using TeX Live 2014 with kile as the editor. Usually I compile `.tex` files using kile's compilation button. There is no errors and no warnings, the output is complete.

When I compile the same file from the terminal, there is the warning (this is just the beginning of the terminal output):

```
warning: Could not open char translation file `utf-8.tcx'.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
```

The output is different: there is no polish characters, the font looks different.

Here is the `.tex` file:

```
%& --translate-file=utf-8
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\section[A]{Ab}

\subsection{B}

\textsc{F}: x \\*
\textsc{D}: xx\\*
\textsc{S}: xxx \\*

\vspace{1mm}

blablabla.
\vspace{2mm}

\emph{N?} \\*
śląź żań 
\vspace{2mm} 

\end{document}
```

Here is the screenshot of the `.dvi` output generated using terminal: [image]

Here is the screenshot of the `.dvi` output generated using kile's compilation button: [image]

When I compile the same file to `.pdf` via terminal, there is no font problems, even if the same warning appears.

I've found out this problem while trying to use `latex2rtf`, there are also problems with the `.rtf` files, so I'd like to make sure that the `.tex` file is fine.

UPDATE:

I've removed from the code the line `%& --translate-file=utf-8`. This time there is no warning, but stil the in output generated via terminal there are font problems. Pdf is stil fine.

Comment: You have dvi in the title and tagged the question dvi but you are using pdflatex, are you not generating pdf rather than dvi?

Comment: You are using inputenc so don't want `translation-file=utf-8` but I could not get your bad output in either case

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I'm calling latex and the terminal output begin with what I've put in my question, so `pdfTeX`, even if it generates .dvi file. The terminal output is the same if I run latex or pdflatex, just the output is different .

Comment: `latex` is preloading the `pdflatex` format? That would be rather an unusual setup (possible though, and still possible to get dvi output by setting `\pdfoutput` to 0) but most distributions have separate formats for latex and pdflatex.

Comment: I've installed TeXlive following the instructions from the Silex reply to question `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu` and I don't remember changing anything in kile's settings. I can still generate `.pdf` file.